# How to add submenu items to menuitems

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, tablelayout, menu-items

I have created a Table layout in windows forms as shown in figure, i have added a right mouse button click Menu to my table,

i wnt to add submenu items to following menuitems such as

When i click `add device` it should show subitems such as `sounder`, `MCP`, `strobe` etc 
When i click `fault`  it should show subitems such as `open circuit fault`, `sounder fault`, `short circuit fault' so on

This is how i created menuitems

```
    ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem addDevice = new MenuItem("Add Device");
    MenuItem deleteDevice = new MenuItem("delete Device");
    MenuItem fire = new MenuItem("Fire");
    MenuItem fault = new MenuItem("Fault");
    MenuItem suppress = new MenuItem("Suppress");
    m.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { addDevice, deleteDevice, fire, fault,suppress});
    tableLayout.ContextMenu = m;
    m.Show((Control)(sender), e.Location);
```

The below is my form and table layout

[image: http://i48.tinypic.com/33ok3cw.jpg]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add `MenuItems` to existing `MenuItem` like:

```
MenuItem addDevice = new MenuItem("Add Device");
addDevice.MenuItems.Add( new MenuItem("Add More .."));
```

It would be visible like:

[image]

Comment: How to add click event to these submenu items?

Comment: @hs.chandra, you can add event through [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c524thtw.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuItem newMenuItem1 = new MenuItem("Employee Master");
            MenuItem mnuSubMenuItem = new MenuItem();
            newMenuItem1.ChildItems.Add(mnuSubMenuItem);
            mnuSubMenuItem.Text = "Add User...";
            mnuSubMenuItem.NavigateUrl = "ADDURL.aspx";

            MenuItem mnuSubMenuItem1 = new MenuItem();
            newMenuItem1.ChildItems.Add(mnuSubMenuItem1);
            mnuSubMenuItem1.Text = "Edit User...";
            mnuSubMenuItem1.NavigateUrl = "EDITURL.aspx";
            this.MenuMaster.Items.Add(newMenuItem1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add This

```
var someMenu= new MenuItem("Foo");
someMenu.MenuItems.Add( new MenuItem("foo "));
```

Answer (score 0):

That format doesn't work for me.  I'm forced to use:

```
// People often exclude the applicable "using" statements--so samples don't work!
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 

// Create the MAIN menu item
MenuItem mnuMenuItem = new MenuItem();         

// Create the SUB menu item
MenuItem mnuSubMenuItem = new MenuItem();      

// Create the SUB menu item, "under" the MAIN menu item!
mnuMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(mnuSubMenuItem);
```