# How to add list into list?

Tags: c#

Ok i have this :

```
if(something!=null)
{
  SubMenu.Add(new SubMenuModel("PERSONAL_INFORMATION","account.personalinformation","/account/personalinformation"));
}
  if(something123!=null)
{        
   SubMenu.Add(new SubMenuModel("NOTIFICATIONS", "account.notificationsettings", "/account/notifications"));
}
      SubMenu.Add(new SubMenuModel("CHANGE_PASSWORD", "account.changepassword", "/account/passwordchange"));
      SubMenu.Add(new SubMenuModel("GAME_SETTINGS", "default", "default"));

    MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel("SETTINGS", "default", "default", true,




           }));
```

EDIT:

```
public List<SubMenuModel> SubMenu { get; set; } 
public List<MainMenuModel> MainMenu { get; set; }
```

How can i add this `SubMenu` into `Main menu` because i have condition so if condition is !=null add to list...any sugesstion?

Comment: What type of is SubMenu and MainMenu? It should be possible by using linq queries.

Comment: public List<SubMenuModel> SubMenu { get; set; }
        public List<MainMenuModel> MainMenu { get; set; }

Comment: You can add a list into another list with .AddRange() but this will only work if SubMenuModel and MainMenuModel have the same baseclass.

Comment: They dont have same baseclass

Comment: @cansik any simple suggestion? :)

Comment: you could also just create a Property on you MainMenuModel that stores a list of SubMenuModel.

Comment: @Boot750 i have this in main menu     public List<SubMenuModel>SubMenu { get; set; }

Comment: If you would have this Property on you MainMenuModel you could just add them to your MainMenu over this Propoerty or also pass it over the Constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83410/discussion-between-uzhas-and-boot750).

Answer (score 4):

you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825568/append-a-lists-contents-to-another-list-c-sharp).

you have just to do `MainMenu.AddRange(SubMenu);`

Hope i helps you

EDIT : Ok so you can make this i think You can add MenuItems to existing MenuItem like:

```
MenuItem addDevice = new MenuItem("Add Device");
addDevice.MenuItems.Add( new MenuItem("Add More .."));
It would be visible like:
```

[image: submenu]

I see this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146801/how-to-add-submenu-items-to-menuitems) and it works for me.

Comment: i cant use MainMenu.AddRange(SubMenu); because SubMenu is type of SubMenuModel.....

Answer (score 0):

If your MainMenu and SubMenu share same property or method I suggest you to use interface.

```
    public interface IMenu
    {
        int a { get; set; }
        string b {get; set; }
    }

    public class SubMenu : IMenu
    {
        public int a { get; set; }

        public string b { get; set; }

        public double c { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainMenu : IMenu
    {
        public int a { get; set; }

        public string b { get; set; }

        public string d { get; set; }
    }
```

So you can use addrange like this

```
        List<IMenu> menuList = new List<IMenu>();
        List<MainMenu> mainMenuList = new List<MainMenu>();
        List<SubMenu> subMenuList = new List<SubMenu>();

        menuList .AddRange(mainMenuList);
        menuList .AddRange(subMenuList);
```

Edit::

Suggest by this sentence of you "@Boot750 i have this in main menu public ListSubMenu { get; set; }"

So just do it like this

```
var mainMenu = new List<MainMenu>();
var subMenuToAdd = new List<SubMenu>().Add(new SubMenu() { .. });

mainMenu.SubMenu = subMenuToAdd;
```